# What will be the return variable for 'int' type function (sql query function)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below I declare a function in witch type is 'int'. I am declare this function for sql query that give int as output. Here I have to return something . But I can't understand what I return in this 'int' type function.

```
    public int Login(LoginClass loginClassObj)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=LoginTest;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        string query = @"SELECT COUNT(log_in) FROM login_table WHERE username = '"+loginClassObj.Username+"' AND password = '"+loginClassObj.Password+"'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return ???;  
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to return anything? What do you want the function to tell you when it is done?

Comment: If it really is your function, you'd better know what to return. You designed the signature!

Comment: It depends upon what you're trying to achieve. You could return `return command.ExecuteNonQuery();` if you need the affected rows count. You could `return 42;`. Or, please clarify your question to get answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work and address most of the problems:

```
public bool Login(LoginClass loginClassObj)
{
    string connectionString = ...
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(log_in) FROM login_table
                                WHERE username = @username AND hash = @hash";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", loginClassObj.Username);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("hash", loginClassObj.GetSecureHash());
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        return count == 1;
    }
}
```

In many cases, though, you may need to do an initial query just on the username to find the salt - presumably retreiving the hash at the same time, then use the salt to perform the secure hash, and compare the locally computed hash to the stored hash.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you've got a query... but for some reason you're calling `ExecuteNonQuery`. You should be specifying `ExecuteScalar` in order to fetch a single value. You can then cast the result to `int`:

```
return (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```

I assume that the point is to return the number of matching users, although that's a little odd.

Additionally:

- You should use `using` statements for the connection and command, so they get disposed appropriately
- Never, ever embed values into the SQL like this - use parameterized SQL instead, to avoid SQL injection attacks and other issues. See the documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.
- If you've *really* got the password directly in the database, that's a significant issue. Hopefully it's actually a digest of some description
- It's not clear *why* you've declared the method to return `int` to start with. Perhaps you should have declared it to return `bool` instead? Was the method declaration given to you? You should always know the meaning of the parameters and return types - otherwise you can't possibly implement the method properly.

Comment: As a side note; the "possibly `long` then `int`" also depends on the specific RDBMS being used.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks. Any idea for SQL Server, as that's presumably what's in use here? (I think it's probably best to keep this one simple...)

Comment: `count` returns `int` on SQL Server; `long` on mysql and oracle, IIRC

Comment: definitely `int` for SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx; the other two I know mainly via "dapper" bugs ;p